Can you create an array/vector of arbitrary length in Mathematica/Wolfram language?
I am working on a small proof/demonstration of how the least squares method gives us the arithmetic mean.
Wolfram Language 14.0.0 Engine for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2023 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= X := {x1, x2, x3}

In[2]:= Err[mu_] := X - mu

In[3]:= SSE[mu_] := Total[Err[mu]^2]

In[4]:= SSE'[mu]

Out[4]= -2 (-mu + x1) - 2 (-mu + x2) - 2 (-mu + x3)

In[5]:= Solve[SSE'[mu] == 0, mu]

                x1 + x2 + x3
Out[5]= {{mu -> ------------}}
                     3

I would like a more general version where X has an arbitrary length, X := {x1, x2, x3, ... , xn}. Is there a way to express a vector of variable length? What I am ultimately looking for is mu -> (x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + xn) / n.

So what you are ultimately looking for is mu->Mean[X] where you delay actually calculating mu until you give it some concrete X.  Can you think about your code is a way that it delays performs any calculation until it is finally given the value of X?

Don't forget there's a dedicated Mathematica StackExchange.

I'm not certain if this is what you're looking for, but Symbol[] can be used to create symbols from text:
In[1] := Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[10]
Out[1] = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10}

